# How Compare CurrentMessage.GetDisplayMessageBody() with string value

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver, string-comparison

I'm developing an app where I'm comparing a received SMS text with and existing string variable if texts Match Toast pops up else doesn't Where am I doing wrong ?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    final String pwd = "123";


    if(bundle != null)
    {

        final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

            SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
            String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

            String senderNum = phoneNumber;
            String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();


            Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
            if(message == pwd)
            {


           // Show Alert
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                         message, duration);
            toast.show();
           }
            else
            {
                 int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,  "Doesn't match", duration);
                 toast.show();
            }


        } // end for loop
```

But condition is not getting true .. always " else's " toast is showing!

Answer (score 0):

In case of comparing Strings use:

```
if(message.equals(pwd))
```

insted of:

```
if(message == pwd)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i change my phone volume from silent to 100% loud if message.equals(pwd) condition get true ?

Comment: if my answer helps you, you can accept(Like) it. for other query you have to put new question.

Comment: I would love to Vote up your Answer but My reputation is not enough to vote 
Thanks though!

Comment: Mr @Rahul Sharma Can you Help me with this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984427/audiomanger-doesnt-work-application-crashes