# AudioManger doesn't Work Application Crashes

Tags: android, crash, broadcastreceiver, android-audiomanager

I'm working on an application .. but Audiomanager is not working i can't see any error my application got crash on phone 
I'm using AudioManager in BroadCastReciver Class when sms recive and text of sms is same of the particular text i've set the volume should be change silent to Normal mode.

```
if(message.equals(pwd)) {

    AudioManager au;
    au = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    au.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

    // Show Alert
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Volumn Changed By Phone Finder App", duration);
    toast.show();
}
else {

    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,  "Doesn't match", duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: Please, post your logcat message. What does it say?

Comment: If you just want to set volume to full, try this: **int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  au.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);**

Comment: @  au = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
GetSystemService shows an error like method is undefined for this type
then i right clicked and click on create method 
it created a method with same name and that method is returning Null.. 
I think this is the problem!

Comment: Please post your class and logcat error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well without crash.
Please paste log report of crash.

And its better to check `context`, `message` and `pwd` for `NullPointer Exception`.

Comment: @  au = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
GetSystemService shows an error like method is undefined for this type
then i right clicked and click on create method 
it created a method with same name and that method is returning Null.. 
I think this is the problem!